# What does widget-connection mean and how it works?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am learning hybris and I am stuck at widget creation. While creating a widget there is a tag , what does it do and why it's used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's cover the basics first:

- in the Backoffice, everything you see is a widget
- widgets declare so-called "sockets". Widgets can send and receive events on sockets (the same idea as "signals and slots" from Qt, for example)

And now you may ask yourself:
How can I configure which widgets sends data do which other widget?

And that's where `widget-connection` comes in. With this tag, you can define that the data/event emitted by widget A on slot A1 is received by widget B on slot B2, for example.

Check out the ["Backoffice Framework Architecture" page on help.hybris.com](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8c16c4a5866910148cccf12def0f2a65.html) and all the sub-pages underneath it for the in-depth explanation for all Backoffice concepts

Comment: Thanks, @Sukram. Actually, I am trying to understand how to use <widget-connection> for multiple widgets and connect them via *-widget.xml and make them appear in the explorerTree.